# How can I raise an exception whenever certain math errno values are set?

Tags: c++, exception

I need to be able to globally stop the execution of my C++ code whenever only certain values of the global variable `errno` are set (more specifically, I'm only interested in the value for domain errors `EDOM`).

I have seen that the library `math_errhandling` allows the utilization of the constant `MATH_ERREXCEPT` in order to raise automatically an error for every kind of math error.

In my case, I am interested in having the automatic raise of an `FE_INVALID` for every domain error that happens in my code.

However, my code already handles by itself certain typologies of math errors such as divde-by-zero errors. For that reason, the automatic raise of an `FE_DIVBYZERO` would be completely unwanted.

Is there a practical way to achieve this partial exception raising with `math_errhandling` or any other C++ library? Or alternately, how can I implement by myself an exception raising based on checking the value of `errno`?

Comment: Note that the exceptions that could be "raised" by match functions are part of the math functions specifications. There's no general or generic way to raise exceptions of any kind for arbitrary values of `errno`. Also note that these exceptions aren't C++ exceptions that you can use in a C++ `try ... catch` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you refer to `math_errhandling` from C++. That's not a library, that is an implementation-defined constant which **tells you** how the implementation handles error handling. You can't change the value of this constant through C++, although you might change its value by certain compiler options (check your documentation).

Even so, the standard only defines possible values `MATH_ERRNO==1`, `MATH_ERREXCEPT==2` and    (implicitly) `MATH_ERRNO | MATH_ERREXCEPT==3`. You wonder about `MATH_ERREXCEPT`. That merely means you can call `std::fetestexcept(FE_INVALID)` after each call. It is not an automatic `throw` of a real C++ exception which you can `catch`.

The underlying problem is that C++ doesn't really match modern FP hardware, which is vector-oriented. For high-performance code, the compiler will merge many operations, but the C++ exception model presumes that you can pinpoint the exact failing operation. IEEE754 suffers less from this because it has less precise error handling. Using `NaN` allows for more parallelism.

Comment: I see! Thank you for the useful clarifications!